# HTML / CSS Create a giant dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

In my buttons I implemented a simple dropdown, as shown in the image.
What I intend at this moment is that in one of these buttons the dropdown is a kind of mega menu, as will be illustrated in the example image.
Can you help me?

Image with my simple dropdown ----> https://i.stack.imgur.com/80yIz.jpg

Image with an example of the dropdown i would like to have ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/WweLS.jpg

I liked to get something of the genre, but with my styles.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header_aera" id="main_navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-10 p0">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="min_navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu other_dropdwn">
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services-2.html">Services-2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There are many ways to go about this, would either of the below links help you?
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0lMgD
https://codepen.io/redfrost/pen/CvFpD

Comment: I'll try to implement. I have both html codes of the images ... More I like to deck myself immensely in css.